# sensors shows me temperatures like -78°C

Tags: fan

I was trying to make my cpu fan less noisy, at first pwmconfig didn't showed my anything after following a small guide it worked but I still don't know how to decrease the RPM. Now I notice that sensors shows me following:

```
it8728-isa-0a30
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +2.22 V  (min =  +0.84 V, max =  +2.32 V)
in1:          +2.22 V  (min =  +2.71 V, max =  +0.48 V)  ALARM
in2:          +2.02 V  (min =  +0.65 V, max =  +2.52 V)
+3.3V:        +3.36 V  (min =  +6.00 V, max =  +4.13 V)  ALARM
in4:          +3.06 V  (min =  +2.74 V, max =  +0.95 V)  ALARM
in5:          +3.06 V  (min =  +2.29 V, max =  +2.24 V)  ALARM
in6:          +2.22 V  (min =  +2.50 V, max =  +1.45 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.29 V  (min =  +0.17 V, max =  +2.16 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.22 V  
fan1:        2647 RPM  (min =  631 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =   85 RPM)  ALARM
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =   28 RPM)  ALARM
temp1:        -68.0°C  (low  = +22.0°C, high =  +5.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp2:        +23.0°C  (low  = -87.0°C, high = -73.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:        -77.0°C  (low  = -11.0°C, high = +37.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
intrusion0:  ALARM
```

I'm worried about that -68°C and -77°C

Have I messed with some configuration? How can I fix it?
In Windows the fan has always been way quieter.. I was searching the internet but only found how to fix sensors by runing sensors-detect which I already did.

Sorry for my bad english and I hope you can help me :)

Comment: To check the sensors you could first try to read them from windows since there the fan reacts differently. To rule out own misdoing you could try a live cd and check if the sensor readings are the same (take 15.10 to be sure you have the latest drivers)

Comment: I broke my windows and i don't want to install it again either. I'll check it with a live usb, thats a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

So my result of sensors on a live usb

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +36.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                   (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                   (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +35.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +26.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +31.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +35.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +34.0°C  (high = +85.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

it just disappeared.. Ill try sensors-detect..

I dont get sensors to display more, I installed fancontrol and run sensors-detect multiple times. pwmconfig shows "There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed"

I guess thats because my system isnt updated / upgraded as its an life system (sorry for no apostrophs, etc. every special letter hurts as i havent the correct input language on my life system)

Dont know how to continue..